# Proof of (left) Ore condition implies there exists Q(R) a left quotient ring of R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 7.1.1 of `Noncommutative Rings' I. N. Herstein.

> Definition: An element in a ring is said to be **regular** if it is neither a left nor a right zero divisor in $R$.

Let $Q(R)$ be the left quotient ring of $R$.

> Theorem 7.1.1: A necessary and sufficient condition that $R$ have a left quotient ring is: given $a,b \in R$ with $b$ regular then $\exists a_1, b_1 \in R$ with $b_1$ regular such that $b_1 a = a_1 b$.

The proof $Q(R) \Rightarrow$ Ore condition is straight forward. However given the Ore condition, WTS there exists $Q(R)$, I have been stuck on a detail on the proof which says: Let $\mathcal{M} := \{(a,b) | a,b \in R, b\text{ regular} \}$ and we define the following relation $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if $d_1a = b_1c$ where $b_1d = d_1b$, $b_1$ regular. *Hence it also follows that $d_1$ is regular.*

I can figure out why $d_1$ is not a right zero divisor from the equation $b_1d = d_1b$ where $b_1,d$ and $b$ are regular elements. How do we show that $d_1$ is also NOT a left zero divisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in, for example, II.3 of Michael Artin’s notes
[https://math.mit.edu/~etingof/artinnotes.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/artinnotes.pdf)

We have $t=d_1b$ is regular (since it equals $b_1d$ which is regular). We next use the Ore condition to write $xt=yb$ with $y$ regular. Now
$$ xd_1b = xt = yb $$
so
$$ (xd_1-y)b=0. $$
Since $b$ is regular we get $xd_1=y$, which is regular, and hence $d_1$ is not a left zero divisor.

Comment: I always forget we can left/right factor specially when there is no way to cancel by multiplicative inverses! And finding a product which is regular with $d_1$ as a factor on the right is very neat! to prove that $d_1$ itself cannot be a left zero divisor.